# Create filenames from cell entry

Tags: excel

Is there a way to create filenames from the values in a MS Excel spreadsheet?

For example, an Excel spreadsheet contains the values in:

```
A1: trees
A2: grasses
A3: flowers
```

Would there be a method to automate the creation of files with an extension (such as .jpg) added to the filename:

```
tree.jpg
grasses.jpg
flowers.jpg
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is through vba.  But, Stack Overflow is not a code for me or show me where to start site.  If you have existing code that does not work then please put it in your original question using edit and explain exactly what the error is.  If not, then this risks down votes and closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try following sub to do that.

```
Sub CreateFiles()
    For Each Rng In Range("A1:A3")
        FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Rng.Value & ".jpg"
        Open FilePath For Output As #2
        Close #2
    Next
End Sub
```